# Does matrix multiplication distribute over the Hadamard product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-product

I know that the Hadamard product is distributive over addition. But suppose that $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then can we say

$$v^T (A \circ B) v = v^TAv \cdot v^TBv$$

where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product, $\cdot$ is standard scalar multiplication, and the rest are matrix-vector multiplications?

Comment: Hint: what happens with this equality if you replace $v$ with $2v$?

Comment: @Aphelli oh, I see: then we have a problem, so it is too good to be true

Comment: A potential point of interest: we have
$$
v^T(A \circ B)v = \sum_{i,j}((A \circ B) \circ [vv^T])_{i,j} = 
 \sum_{i,j}(\operatorname{diag}(v)(A \circ B) \operatorname{diag}(v))_{i,j}
$$

Comment: Distribution only occurs if $v$ is a cartesian basis vectors {$e_k$} in which case
$$\eqalign{
(A\circ B)e_j &= (Ae_j)\circ(Be_j) \\
e_i^T(A\circ B) &= (e_i^TA)\circ(e_i^TB) \\
}$$
Putting these together yields
$$\eqalign{
e_i^T(A\circ B)e_j
 &= (e_i^TAe_j)\circ(e_i^TBe_j)
 \;=\; A_{ij} B_{ij} \\
}$$